Convert Multivariate PDF to Anomaly based Risk Score on scale 0 to 1
I have defined a multi-variate normal distribution over a number of risk factors.
Currently the PDF over the risk factor observations ranges from infinitesimally values to a maximum of ~2.1.
While the smaller PDFs do indicate how anomalous an observation is, I'd like this on an interpretable 'risk scale' from 0 to 1, where 1 indicates that it is highly anomalous and 0 that it is as expected (all risk factor values are 0).
I have tried using the follow logic over the PDF values:
(max_PDF - obs_PDF)/(max_PDF - min_PDF).
However the issue here is that a proportion of observations are rounded to 1 and close to 1, then there is a steep drop off to 0. In other words, the scale itself is non-linear (likely due to the normal assumption?).
Any assistance here would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
